# OpenLayers RenderComplete event callback use of this context inside callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers, gif

I have an [GIF.js](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/) object in my `this` object which I would like to `this.gif.addframe(mapcanvas)` in a loop that goes through a date array at the end of which I `this.gif.render()`. I must make use of `this` inside the callback which I understand would be possible if I were to cache it and use an arrow function but I need to have something like

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < this.dateArraySurface10.length-2 ; i++)
{
    this.setTimeSurface10();
    this.map.renderSync();
    var self = this;
    const mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
        const divElement = document.querySelector(".map");
        mapCanvas.width = divElement.offsetWidth;//size[0];
        mapCanvas.height = divElement.offsetHeight;//size[1];
        const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
        function (canvas) {
            if (canvas.width > 0) {
            const opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
            mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
            const transform = canvas.style.transform;
            const matrix = transform
                .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1] //eslint-disable-line
                .split(',')
                .map(Number);
            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
                mapContext,
                matrix
            );
            mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        );
        self.gif.addFrame(mapCanvas, {copy:true, delay: 200});
        console.log(i);                    
    });
}
this.gif.on('finished', function(blob) { 
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});
this.gif.render();

}
```

where

```
setTimeSurface10: function () {
   if (this.currentTimeSurface10 === null) {
      this.currentTimeSurface10 = this.startTimeSurface10;
   } else if (this.currentTimeSurface10 >= this.endTimeSurface10) {
      this.currentTimeSurface10 = this.startTimeSurface10;
   } else {
      this.currentTimeSurface10 = new Date(
         this.currentTimeSurface10.setMinutes(
         this.currentTimeSurface10.getMinutes() + 60)
      );
   }
   this.surface10.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: 
   this.currentTimeSurface10.toISOString().split(".")[0] + "Z" });
}
```

This is nothing but pseudo code since for the moment I managed to produce a very boring GIF that adds the same frame over and over again using the let vm = this and arrow function pattern. Can someone explain to me how I am to access and use this inside my callback inside my loop?

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the callback is the map object.  If you cannot use arrow functions (e.g. you must support old browsers) assign a variable to `this` before setting the listener

```
for(date in dateArray) {
   this.map.setTime(date)
   var self = this;
   this.map.on('renderComplete', function() {
      self.gif.addFrame(mapcanvas)
   }
}
this.gif.render()
```

Comment: Mr. @Mike thank you for your time. I tried what you suggest but do not seem to get the results I am looking for and do not even get an error message that I can use for research. I believe it is because I am creating a copy of this (i.e. self) to which I add the frame just as I tried before therefore when I tried to render the "global" GIF it is empty. I need to add the frame on rendercomplete to the global this.gif sir.